# Numeric pre tags removal with Jquery

Tags: jquery, tags, numeric

Is there any way to remove the pre tags which covered numeric using Jquery?

For example, I have the following content :

```
<pre>1000</pre>
```

**I need to remove the PRE tags using Jquery..**

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note, David Thomas provides a good example of how to use `.unwrap()` with `firstchild`.)

There's [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$("pre").wrapInner('<div>').find('div').unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4j77/

You could also do this:

```
$("pre").parent().each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4j77/1/

Answer (score 2):

I think the following would work, to unwrap the textNode:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
    $(this.firstChild).unwrap();
});
```

Because I don't know if *all* the `pre` elements will be purely numeric, I've added an `if` check to look and see if the element contains alpha characters (a-z, upper and lower-case):

```
$('pre').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text.match(/[a-z]/gi)){
        // you've got a string with letters
    }
    else {
        $(this.firstChild).unwrap();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/US983/).

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, I had incorrect markup; this works at least in FF8. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8P6Fq/

Answer (score 1):

So simple:

```
$("pre").contents().unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4j77/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").html($("#element").html().replace(/<\/?pre>/i, ''));
```